# PowerShell Convert output to hashtable array (data type conversion)

Tags: powershell, sccm

This a data type conversion issue.

I am trying to get the names of computers out of SCCM and feed it into SCCM Report. The report commandlet receives hashtable where the variable must be named "Computer Name".  The value is the computer name.

```
ex. $computer = @{"Computer Name" = "MyComp01"}
```

Outputing Commandlet example (get computer names from SCCM) This works.

```
$unknownoutputtype = Get-CMDevice -CollectionName "My Collection Computers" | select @{N="Computer Name";E={$_.Name}}

--Output--

Computer Name
-------------
MyComp01
MyComp02
MyComp03
MyComp04
MyComp05
MyComp06

PS> $unknownoutputtype.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Recieving Commandlet example (process the query) This works:

```
$computer = @{"Computer Name" = "MyComp01"}
invoke-cmreport -ReportPath "Software - Companies and Products/Software registered in Add Remove Programs on a specific computer"  -reportparameter $Computer -OutputFormat excel
```

---

I need the "Get-CMDevice" line to output as the type below.

```
PS> $Computer.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Hashtable                                System.Object
```

---

My failed attempt

```
PS> Get-CMDevice -CollectionName "My Collection Computers" |select @{N="Computer Name";E={$_.Name}} | Foreach-object {invoke-cmreport -ReportPath "Software - Companies and Products/Software registered in Add Remove Programs on a specific computer" -SiteCode "MySite" -reportparameter $_ -OutputFormat Excel}
```

Error output:

```
Invoke-CMReport : Cannot bind parameter 'ReportParameter'. Cannot convert value "@{Computer Name=MyComp01}" to type "System.Collections.Hashtable". Error: "Cannot convert the "@{Computer Name=MyComp01}" value of type
"Selected.Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider.WqlQueryEngine.WqlResultObject" to type "System.Collections.Hashtable"."
At line:1 char:280
+ ... s on a specific computer" -SiteCode "{removed}" -reportparameter $_ -Output ...
+                                                                ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-CMReport], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.Cmdlets.Reporting.Commands.InvokeReportCommand
```

Comment: try instead of select:
`foreach-object { @{ $_.Name = $_.Name }}`

Select return objects, not a hash

Answer (score 2):

`Select-Object` will always output a `PSCustomObject`, not a hashtable.

Just construct the hashtable inside the `ForEach-Object` body before calling `Invoke-CMReport`:

```
Get-CMDevice -CollectionName "My Collection Computers" |Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | Foreach-object {
    $ReportParameter = @{ 'Computer Name' = $_ }
    invoke-cmreport -ReportPath "Software - Companies and Products/Software registered in Add Remove Programs on a specific computer" -SiteCode "MySite" -reportparameter $ReportParameter -OutputFormat Excel
}
```

Comment: Mathias R. Jessen is a saint and scholar.  Thank you.

Comment: @Aaron I'm very flattered ^_^ if my answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left